# I am creating a Firefox webextension which captures Mousewheel scroll and does something, but I am unable to do so

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Here is the manifest file

```
{
"description": "",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "A",
    "version": "0.2.0.2",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",     
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs"
    ],

    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/48.png",
        "96": "icons/96.png"

    },


    "background": {
        "scripts" : ["background.js", "mouseWheel.js"]
    }
}
```

The mouseWheel.js file is:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseWheel);
function mouseWheel(e) {
console.log("Scroll capture Working");
}
```

Whenever I scroll at any page, it should print Scroll capture Working. But there is no response.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executing in a background page: an invisible tab with its own document (and its own console).

So, when you attach to `window` events, they are events in that (invisible) tab, not actual browser tabs.

Go read the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). It will explain that you need to switch to [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) if you need to interact with content in "real" tabs. Read that documentation thoroughly, but as a quickstart, this will give you what you want (in the manifest):

```
"content_scripts" : [{
  "matches" : ["<all_urls>"],
  "js" : ["mouseWheel.js"]
}],
```